# Finding the total probability under a shape in a bivariate KDE plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kernel-density

I have a set of points stored as (x,y) values. My goal is the map these onto a coordinate plane and create a continuous PDF distribution.

I would like to apply polygons to the figure and get the total summed probability under the shape and return that to the user. The shape would be stored as a series of coordinates, so [(0,0), (1,0), (1,1),(0,1),(0,0)] would represent a square.

So far, I have plotted the points using a seaborn.kdeplot, and that generates a beautiful plot, which the sum of every point adds to around 100%.

However, I am struggling to effectively apply shapes directly the the graph. I've tried a few online solutions, but have been unable to find any method to get the cumulative probability under a shape directly on the kde plot. My code is below:

```
def get_field_matrix(csv_name, coordinates):
    
    # ... Some code that loads in a csv and names it df_heatmap
    # df_heatmap has two columns, ActualX and ActualY which are the series of points for the kde
    
    # Create a KDE-based heatmap using seaborn
    kde = sns.kdeplot(x='ActualX', y='ActualY', data=df_heatmap, cmap='viridis', fill=True, cbar=True, weights=np.linalg.norm(df_heatmap, axis=1) ** .3)
    
    # Set labels and title
    plt.xlabel('X-axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
    plt.title('KDE-based Heatmap of X, Y Coordinates')

    # Coordinates is the list of tuples that make up the shape to be applied. 
    # Any shape may be represented, but it will always be a shape draw with a single line
    # Creates a matplotlib path out of the coordinates
    shape_path = Path(coordinates)
    shape_patch = PathPatch(shape_path, lw=0)
    plt.gca().add_patch(shape_patch)

    print("Summed Probability over the shape:", "A")

    # Set aspect ratio to be equal
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
    return kde
```

Is there some library function I am missing to apply the cdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below shows how you can place a patch over a KDE plot, and integrate the area underneath.

I don't think the KDE data from `seaborn` (left) is directly accessible, so I've run a separate KDE (right) that tries to match `seaborn`.

The green points represent the user-defined coordinates, and the hatched area is just to confirm that the patch has been correctly interpolated onto the same grid as the KDE data.

[image]

A KDE estimator is first fitted to the data, and then used to get a KDE estimate over a fine grid. The user-defined patch coordinates are used to build a triangulated surface, which is then interpolated onto the fine rectangular grid from before. The patch and KDE are now in the same space. They are finally multiplied and integrated over.

---

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#
# Create test dataset
#
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
np.random.seed(0)
X, _ = make_moons(n_samples=500, noise=0.1)
X_df = pd.DataFrame({'x0': X[:, 0], 'x1': X[:, 1]})

kde_thresh = 0.05 #default sns clipping

if True: #View datapoints
    sns.kdeplot(
        X_df, x='x0', y='x1', cmap='inferno', alpha=0.4,
        thresh=kde_thresh, cbar=True
    )
    sns.scatterplot(X_df, x='x0', y='x1', color='black', marker='.')
    sns_limits = plt.axis()
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 3)
    plt.title('seaborn kde plot')
    plt.show()

#
# Model using kernel density estimator
#
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
kd_estimator = gaussian_kde(X_df.values.T, bw_method='scott')

#Create grid for plotting estimator results
x_axis = np.linspace(sns_limits[0], sns_limits[1], num=200) #200 is sns kde default
y_axis = np.linspace(sns_limits[2], sns_limits[3], num=200)
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_axis, y_axis)

xy_paired = np.column_stack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()])
kde_scores = kd_estimator.evaluate(xy_paired.T).reshape(x_grid.shape)

from matplotlib import ticker
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.2, 3))
c = ax.contour(
    x_grid, y_grid, np.ma.masked_less(kde_scores, kde_thresh),
    cmap='inferno', alpha=0.5
)
ax.scatter('x0', 'x1', data=X_df, marker='.', color='black', s=7)
ax.figure.colorbar(c, ticks=ticker.MaxNLocator(10))
ax.set(xlabel='x0', ylabel='x1')
ax.set_title('manual kde plot')

#
# Place a patch over the KDE
#

#User-defined patch
# patch = np.array( [[-2, -2], [2, -2], [2, 2], [-2, 2]] )     #most of the area
# patch = np.array( [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)] ) #square
# patch = np.array( [(0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)] )             #triangle
patch = np.array( [(0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (.8, .8), (0,1)] )   #concave

patch_x = patch[:, 0]
patch_y = patch[:, 1]

#View patch
ax.scatter(patch_x, patch_y, marker='o', color='darkgreen', alpha=0.7)
ax.fill(patch_x, patch_y, color='darkgreen', linestyle='none', alpha=0.5)

#Map patch onto 2D xy grid
import matplotlib.path as mpath
patch_path = mpath.Path(np.column_stack([patch_x, patch_y]))
patch_interp = patch_path.contains_points(
    np.column_stack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()])
).reshape(x_grid.shape)
patch_interp = np.where(patch_interp, 1, 0)

#Visually confirm that the polygon has been correctly mapped onto the rectilinear grid
ax.contourf(x_grid, y_grid, patch_interp, levels=[0.9, 1], hatches=['//'], colors='none')

#
#Finally, extract the KDE portion and integrate its area
#
kde_patch = kde_scores * patch_interp
grid_area = np.diff(x_axis)[0] * np.diff(y_axis)[0]
area = (kde_patch * grid_area).sum()

ax.set_title(r'$\int KDE$ over patch is ' + f'{area:.3f}')
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer! One question, would this code work on concave shapes? I've tried and I am not quite getting the right answer. For example, a traingular patch with coordinates [(0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)] returns a probability of .12. Changing it to (0, 1), (1,1), (1,0), (.95,.95), (0,1), [which makes it a boomerang-shaped figure with far less area] still gets the same .12. How could the code be modified to fix this?

Comment: Thanks. I've used another method now and it looks like it's working with concave polygons.

Comment: No problem. I wrap the patch coordinates in a `matplotlib.path.Path` object, giving me `patch_path` which represents the path of the points. I use the `.contains_points()` method to see whether or not each grid point is inside the path or outside of it. The result is a grid where points inside the path are 1, and outside is 0. That's how the patch coordinates are mapped into a filled shape on the grid.

Comment: I am curious - how did you figure all this out? Reading matplotlib documentation? Experience? This code is excellent, I'd like to learn more about how to write it myself! Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. I made a start and incrementally got there by experimentation, figuring out the details as needed. Practice with snippets of example code helps a lot - I've worked through code examples from textbooks and other resources. I get a lot of repetition by coding things up each time I need them, rather than copying and pasting my existing code. I also visualise/plot much of what I work with, which provides a lot of opportunity for honing skills with `matplotlib`. I learn through the process of answering questions like yours. AI tools can help in parts - that's how the `Path` fix came up.

Comment: No problem @cjmess01. Happy to explain this particular code further if required.